# Azure for authentication to multiple applications using the organization's identity provider

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2b

I want to  use Azure  for  authentication to multiple  web applications using the organisation's identity provider.

Organisation has already developed identity provider, but I want to use Azure to authenticate all applications through Organisation's identity provider.

I can see Azure AD B2C option, but I don't want to use any social identities or local Azure identities.

Scenario want to work as below.

User enter https://webapp1.com/home

it should redirect to Organisation IDP

Once it's Authenticated by Organisation's IDP ( with username/password pop up for sign in), it should redirect to https://webapp1.com/home page

If I use Azure B2C ,  local sign in text boxes will be there as unused.
Is there any better options available in Azure to resolve this issue?

I tried Azure AD B2C, but it left with unused username/pass text boxes.  I just want to use single identity provider from Organization.

Answer (score 0):

If your identity provider is Oauth compliant, you can register it as an identity provider in B2C by clicking the New OpenID Connect Provider button on the Identity Providers blade, and then consuming that in your signup/signin flow.

Oath requires a redirect, so if you have a local sign in form, it will not be used. The Identity Provider provides the login screen.

[image]

Comment: Basically I have followed this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-identity-provider#select-an-identity-provider

Reference Image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/media/add-identity-provider/external-idp.png

Here we can see, local account login option (with username/password ) which I am not using.

Basically seemless redirection page looks weird, if we have only 1 sign in option. How can I avoid unwanted things from that page?